# When using Qiskit's plot_bloch_vector function, how can I set colors for vectors?

Tags: qiskit, programming, bloch-sphere

I am able to visualize vectors on a bloch sphere using Qiskit as follows:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector
%matplotlib inline

sv = []
sv.append([0,1,0])
sv.append([0,0,1])
sv.append([1,0,0])

fig = plot_bloch_vector(sv)
fig
```

The code above yields the following result (which looks good):

[image]

Now I would like to adjust the colors of each vector. The API of Qiskit seems not to provide any color parameter for `plot_bloch_vector`. Maybe we can manipulate the `fig` object directly or find another way to adjust vector colors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do that is by using `Bloch` class<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/visualization/bloch.py#L94)</sup> directly which accepts a list of *vector colors* to cycle through:

```
from qiskit.visualization.bloch import Bloch

_bloch = Bloch()
_bloch.vector_color = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

sv = []
sv.append([1,0,0])
sv.append([0,1,0])
sv.append([0,0,1])

_bloch.add_vectors(sv)
_bloch.render()
_bloch.fig
```

The result:

[image]